# C#: Is there a way to only include a project in a build if building on a particular OS?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, cross-platform, monodevelop

I have a simple app that runs on linux using Gtk# for the interface. I want to make a Windows port that uses Wpf for the interface.

All the Gtk interface code is in a separate project, so it should be relatively straightforward to write the code. However, the solution will still contain the Gtk interface project with all the references to assemblies that I don't want to depend on in the Windows port.

Is there a way to make it so that the compiler completely ignores compiling the Gtk assembly when compiling on Windows (perhaps when a particular compiler flag is set)?

I am using MonoDevelop on Ubuntu 11.04 and Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the configuration manager to add a custom platform to the solution (you don't want to add it to the projects - won't work) that does not build the gtk interface project.

As for the references to that project, I believe [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/csharplanguage/thread/580bbae0-4a31-4a3f-95f3-f61e3edf0809) describes how to exclude those references based on configuration. Essentially, you add a condition to the ProjectReference element much like you might in the old style (VS '08 and earlier) MSBuild .proj files.